# Timepicker widget that allows one to define what times are shown

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, widget

I've been looking at time selection widgets (such as jquery.datetimepicker and any+time) and think they are pretty nice and satisfy most of the needs. However there is still one big requirement that I can't seem to find anywhere- the ability to grey out or disable certain times. For example passing it a JSON array of all the times that should not be shown, or something like that. Does anyone know if this exists or if it is possible to modify Any+Time to do this? Just a nudge in the right direction is all I need.

Comment: I guess ideally I'd have something where I could pass something similar to set notation to define what ranges of times should be visible, something like (8,11)+(12,15)+(16,18) to get 0800-1100, 1200-1500, and 1600-1800 all in one widget

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My jQuery Timepicker is very flexible for these kind of configurations.
You can specify a range of visible hours, and you can enable / disble cells.
See the example code for more info.

http://fgelinas.com/code/timepicker

Comment: Is there a feature for advanced sets of time? Like (8-11am) + (12pm-3pm) + (4pm-5pm)?

Answer (score 0):

This is another alternative for a [jQuery timepicker](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/), in which you can easily specify the time intervals you want to display. I have implemented it and it has been broadly accepted by the users.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I was originally trying to get this to work, but i wanted more specific date ranges (like 8-5pm, disable 2pm and 11am), and sliders aren't really the optimal solution for this.